# i have error: no visible interface for 'UIAlertController'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uialertcontroller

I am new to Xcode(7.3) and ios(9.3).I am tried  a sample project to display alert message but i got error like:

"no visible interface for 'UIAlertController' declares the 'show'.Belo i attached the code.

```
//ViewController.m//

UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                                                         message:@"This is an alert."
                                                       preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];
[alert show];


//AppDelegate.h//


@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end.
```

please help me out.

Comment: Hint - where in the documentation for `UIAlertController` do you see the method `show`?

Answer (score 1):

Try instead:

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                                                     message:@"This is an alert."
                                                   preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

[alert addAction:defaultAction];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I tried this option now the error doesn't appear but alert is not displaying.

Answer (score 1):

As you are creating `UIAlertController`, you have to write below code:

```
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

instead of

```
 [alert show];
```

For more detail about `UIAlertController` read: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. show is only available for `UIAlertVIew` but not `UIAlertAction`.

`UIALertAction` is a an action added to `UIAlertController`